# Run Speed (inefficient query)

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql

I have the following query which isnt very efficiant and a lot of the time brings back an out of memory message, can anyone make any recomendations to help speed it up?
Thanks
Jim

```
DECLARE @period_from INT
SET @period_from = 201400

DECLARE @period_to INT
SET @period_to = 201414

Declare @length INT
Set @length = '12'

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '%[^-a-zA-Z0-9() ]%'

SELECT 'dim_2' AS field, NULL AS Length, * FROM table1 WHERE client = 'CL'AND period >= @period_from AND @period_to <= @period_to AND dim_2 LIKE @query
UNION
SELECT 'dim_3' AS field, NULL AS Length, * FROM table1 WHERE client = 'CL'AND period >= @period_from AND @period_to <= @period_to AND dim_3 LIKE @query
UNION
SELECT 'dim_4' AS field, NULL AS Length, * FROM table1 WHERE client = 'CL'AND period >= @period_from AND @period_to <= @period_to AND dim_4 LIKE @query
UNION
SELECT 'dim_5' AS field, NULL AS Length, * FROM table1 WHERE client = 'CL'AND period >= @period_from AND @period_to <= @period_to AND dim_5 LIKE @query
UNION
SELECT 'dim_6' AS field, NULL AS Length, * FROM table1 WHERE client = 'CL'AND period >= @period_from AND @period_to <= @period_to AND dim_6 LIKE @query
UNION
SELECT 'dim_7' AS field, NULL AS Length,* FROM table1 WHERE client = 'CL'AND period >= @period_from AND @period_to <= @period_to AND dim_7 LIKE @query
UNION
SELECT 'ext_inv_ref' AS field, NULL AS Length, * FROM table1 WHERE client = 'CL'AND period >= @period_from AND @period_to <= @period_to AND ext_inv_ref LIKE @query
UNION
SELECT 'ext_ref' AS field, NULL AS Length, * FROM table1 WHERE client = 'CL'AND period >= @period_from AND @period_to <= @period_to AND ext_ref LIKE @query
UNION
SELECT 'description' AS field, NULL AS Length, * FROM table1 WHERE client = 'CL'AND period >= @period_from AND @period_to <= @period_to AND description LIKE @query
UNION
SELECT 'Length dim_2' AS field,LEN(dim_2) as Length, * FROM table1 WHERE client = 'CL'AND period >= @period_from AND @period_to <= @period_to AND dim_2 is not null and len(dim_2) >@length
UNION
SELECT 'Length dim_3' AS field, LEN(dim_3) as Length, * FROM table1 WHERE client = 'CL'AND period >= @period_from AND @period_to <= @period_to AND dim_3 is not null and len(dim_3) >@length
UNION
SELECT 'Length dim_4' AS field, LEN(dim_4) as Length, * FROM table1 WHERE client = 'CL'AND period >= @period_from AND @period_to <= @period_to AND dim_4 is not null and len(dim_4) >@length
UNION
SELECT 'Length dim_5' AS field, LEN(dim_5) as Length, * FROM table1 WHERE client = 'CL'AND period >= @period_from AND @period_to <= @period_to AND dim_5 is not null and len(dim_5) >@length
UNION
SELECT 'Length dim_6' AS field, LEN(dim_6) as Length, * FROM table1 WHERE client = 'CL'AND period >= @period_from AND @period_to <= @period_to AND dim_6 is not null and len(dim_6) >@length
UNION
SELECT 'Length dim_7' AS field, LEN(dim_7) as Length, * FROM table1 WHERE client = 'CL'AND period >= @period_from AND @period_to <= @period_to AND dim_7 is not null and len(dim_7) >@length
```

Comment: What type of database are you using? MS/oracle etc ?

Comment: MS SQL server (sorry forgot the obvious bit!)

Comment: Are the dim fields static? In that case if your RDBMS allows it some UNPIVOT can help to reduce the UNION number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the number of unions significantly, but the work then goes into the WHERE clause. The SQL Query optimiser should figure out that you only need to go through the rows in the table once for each union statement, so it should be quicker. Try it like this and see!

```
SELECT 
CASE 
 WHEN dim_2 like @query Then 'dim_2' 
 WHEN dim_3 like @query Then 'dim_3' 
 WHEN dim_4 like @query Then 'dim_4' 
 WHEN dim_5 like @query Then 'dim_5' 
 WHEN dim_6 like @query Then 'dim_6' 
 WHEN dim_7 like @query Then 'dim_7' 
 WHEN ext_inv_ref LIKE @query Then 'ext_inv_ref'
 WHEN ext_ref LIKE @query Then 'ext_ref'
END AS field, 
NULL AS Length, 
* 
FROM table1 
WHERE client = 'CL'AND period >= @period_from AND @period_to <= @period_to 
AND (dim_2 LIKE @query 
     OR dim_3 LIKE @query 
     OR dim_4 LIKE @query 
     OR dim_5 LIKE @query 
     OR dim_6 LIKE @query 
     OR dim_7 LIKE @query
     OR ext_inv_ref LIKE @query
     OR ext_ref LIKE @query)
```

UNION

```
SELECT 
CASE 
 WHEN dim_2 is not null and len(dim_2) >@length Then 'Length dim_2' 
 WHEN dim_3 is not null and len(dim_3) >@length Then 'Length dim_3' 

 ....     

END AS field, 
LEN(dim_2) as Length,
* 
FROM table1 
WHERE client = 'CL'AND period >= @period_from AND @period_to <= @period_to 
AND ((dim_2 is not null and len(dim_2) >@length)
     OR
     (dim_3 is not null and len(dim_3) >@length)
     OR ....
     )
```

Comment: This is very different from the original query. When a query matches more than one dim then you get only one record instead of one per match. E.g. dim_2 is 'mouse', dim_3 is 'house', @query is '%ouse', then the original query gives you two records, one for dim_2 and one for dim_3. Above query however only gives you the record for dim_2.

Comment: This answer makes the assumption that each row returned will only satisfy one of the WHERE conditions. Nowhere in the OPs introduction does it say how the data is being used or what is trying to be achieved. You could therefore still get the same result in the OPs query as in this query depending on the data!

Comment: Yes, but that isn't likely. Jim, the OP sets @query = '%[^-a-zA-Z0-9() ]%'. So he seems to be looking for all fields where special characters occur.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can optimize this much. The database has dim1 to dim7 as columns of one table. Now you want to treat them as if they were stand-alone columns. So the database design doesn't meet your requirement. If this is just an exception than you will have to live with it. If this usage however becomes the typical access, then one should think about changing the database design and have an additional table for the dimensions.

The one thing you unnecessarily do is to use **UNION** which lets the dbms look out for duplicates. As your records start with a different constant per union group there will be none. Use **UNION ALL** instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things to do there, but you can for example do this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table1 
SELECT * FROM table WHERE client = 'CL' 
AND period >= @period_from AND @period_to <= @period_to;
```

Then use this table as the base for your other unions, then drop it. If you do such selections often, introducing composite index on fields `period` and `client` in your table1 might also help when you are creating that temporary table:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD KEY period_client (client, period);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing you can do, if it is within your power, is to restructure your database so that you move the `dim` fields to a separate table and have only one `dim` column in that table (but more than one row for those cases in which there's more than one `dim` value).  This process is called database normalization.  You will then be able to perform your query with a single `SELECT`, without having to `UNION` together a bunch of `SELECT`s.

For the query as written (and this applies to the improved query with a corrected database structure), you need to find out if indexes are being used to solve the query.  In your case, the best index will be one of `(client, period)` or `(period, client)` depending on the *cardinality* of those indexes (basically, how many different values are present in those columns and how evenly those values are distributed).

If you have one or both of those indexes already, there isn't much you can do without restructuring your database.  If you don't, you can try creating each index in turn and seeing whether it has an effect on the query time.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.field
      ,T.Length
      ,table1.* 
FROM table1
     CROSS APPLY (
          VALUES ('dim_2', dim_2, NULL)
                ,('dim_3', dim_3, NULL)
                ,...
                ,('Length dim_2', NULL, LEN(dim_2))
                ,...
     ) AS T(field, value, Length)
WHERE table1.client = 'CL'
      AND table1.period BETWEEN @period_from AND @period_to 
      AND ((T.Length IS NOT NULL AND T.Length > @Length)
           OR (T.value IS NOT NULL AND T.value LIKE @Query))
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you select your result cost a lot of time because you will query each time to get the dataset you want every time for every record, my solution for you is to query one time and to get the final result at once :

```
/* Part 1 : We will define a function that will help us to decompose a value of a column to multiple rows */

ALTER FUNCTION [audit].[FN_Decompose](@p_liste VARCHAR (MAX), @p_separateur CHAR(1))
RETURNS  @table_result TABLE ([id] INT, [indexAt] INT, [element] VARCHAR (255) NULL)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE  @v_index       INT
            ,@v_i           INT
            ,@v_longueur    INT
            ,@v_element     VARCHAR(MAX)

    IF ISNULL(@p_liste, '') <> '' 
        BEGIN
            SET @v_index        = 1
            SET @v_i            = 1
            SET @v_longueur     = LEN(@p_liste) + 2
            SET @v_element      = ''

            --pour chaque caractère de la liste
            WHILE @v_index <> @v_longueur 
                BEGIN
                    --si le caractère n''est pas un séparateur
                    IF SUBSTRING(@p_liste, @v_index, 1) <> @p_separateur 
                        BEGIN
                            --Ajouter le caractère à     l''élément courant
                            SET @v_element = @v_element +     SUBSTRING(@p_liste, @v_index,1)
                        END
                    ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            --si l''élément courant n''est     pas vide
                            --IF (@v_element <> '')
                                begin
                                    --Ajout à la table
                                INSERT INTO @table_result ([id],[indexAt],element)
                                VALUES (@v_i, @v_index, @v_element)
                                --Ré-initialisation
                                SET @v_element = ''
                                SET @v_i = @v_i + 1
                            END
                    END

                -- Caractère suivant
                SET @v_index = @v_index + 1
            END
    END

INSERT INTO @table_result VALUES (@v_i, @v_index, @v_element)

RETURN

END

GO


/* THE Script */



DECLARE @period_from INT
SET @period_from = 201400

DECLARE @period_to INT
SET @period_to = 201414

Declare @length INT
Set @length = '12'

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '%[^-a-zA-Z0-9() ]%';


WITH Temp AS (
SELECT   
         LEN(dim_2) AS Length_dim2
        ,LEN(dim_3) AS Length_dim3
        ,LEN(dim_4) AS Length_dim4
        ,LEN(dim_5) AS Length_dim5
    ,LEN(dim_6) AS Length_dim6
    ,LEN(dim_7) AS Length_dim7
    ,CASE WHEN dim_1 LIKE @query THEN 'dim_1' ELSE '' END+';'
    +CASE WHEN dim_2 LIKE @query THEN 'dim_2' ELSE '' END+';'
    +CASE WHEN dim_3 LIKE @query THEN 'dim_3' ELSE '' END+';'
    +CASE WHEN dim_4 LIKE @query THEN 'dim_4' ELSE '' END+';'
    +CASE WHEN dim_5 LIKE @query THEN 'dim_5' ELSE '' END+';'
    +CASE WHEN dim_6 LIKE @query THEN 'dim_6' ELSE '' END+';'
    +CASE WHEN dim_7 LIKE @query THEN 'dim_7' ELSE '' END+';'

    +CASE WHEN ext_inv_ref LIKE @query THEN 'ext_inv_ref' ELSE '' END+';'
    +CASE WHEN ext_ref LIKE @query THEN 'ext_ref' ELSE '' END+';'
    +CASE WHEN [description] LIKE @query THEN 'description' ELSE '' END+';'

    +CASE WHEN AND dim_2 is not null and len(dim_2) >@length THEN 'Length dim_2' ELSE '' END+';'
    +CASE WHEN AND dim_3 is not null and len(dim_3) >@length THEN 'Length dim_3' ELSE '' END+';'
    +CASE WHEN AND dim_4 is not null and len(dim_4) >@length THEN 'Length dim_4' ELSE '' END+';'
    +CASE WHEN AND dim_5 is not null and len(dim_5) >@length THEN 'Length dim_5' ELSE '' END+';'
    +CASE WHEN AND dim_6 is not null and len(dim_6) >@length THEN 'Length dim_6' ELSE '' END+';'
    +CASE WHEN AND dim_7 is not null and len(dim_7) >@length THEN 'Length dim_7' ELSE '' END+';' AS fields

FROM table1
WHERE client = 'CL'
AND period >= @period_from
AND @period_to <= @period_to)


SELECT

     CASE fn.element
        WHEN 'Length dim_2' THEN Length_dim2
        WHEN 'Length dim_3' THEN Length_dim3
        WHEN 'Length dim_4' THEN Length_dim4
        WHEN 'Length dim_5' THEN Length_dim5
        WHEN 'Length dim_6' THEN Length_dim6
        WHEN 'Length dim_7' THEN Length_dim7            
     END    AS [Length]
    ,fn.element AS Field
    ,t.* /* The other columns */
FROM Temp t
CROSS APPLY [audit].[FN_Decompose](fields,';') fn
WHERE fn.element IS NOT NULL
```

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand my comment, if you have SQLServer 2005 or better you can unpivot the data to transform the columns to row and than check that

```
SELECT id, column_name, value
FROM   (SELECT id, period, dim_2, dim_3, dim_4, dim_5, dim_6
             , dim_7, ext_inv_ref, ext_ref, description 
        FROM myTable) a
       UNPIVOT
       (value FOR column_name 
        IN (dim_2, dim_3, dim_4, dim_5, dim_6
          , dim_7, ext_inv_ref, ext_ref, description)
       ) unpvt
WHERE (value LIKE '%[^-a-zA-Z0-9() ]%' OR len(value) > 12)
  AND period BETWEEN 201400 AND 201414
```